# How to disable auto scroll to selected cell in ExtJS grid?

Tags: javascript, extjs

How to disable auto scroll to selected (focused) cell in ExtJS grid after ALT+TAB (switch) and return back?
I select a single cell, then i scroll table to the bottom, switch to any other chrome`s tab or application, switch back and grid scrolls to selected cell.
I need to disable this function.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding two lines. Maybe its wrong, but it works for me as i need.

```
Ext.GlobalEvents.events.focus.listeners[0].fireFn=function(){};
Ext.GlobalEvents.events.focus.listeners[0].fn=function(){};
```